# Options for selecting multiple rows and individual rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using JQGrid and I want an option for multiple selection of rows. I used " multiselect: true," but it is not working. Yes I have got an column in the grid that have checkbox in each row but if I select top checkbox which is in header , it just selects first row from grid

Even single selection of row is not working properly. If checked at one checkbox, it selects and then if I check another box in the another row, it unchecks the first checked checkbox.

Here is my grid Code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGetdetails").click(function () {
                bindReports();
            });
            var bindReports = function () {
                $('#list1').jqGrid('GridUnload');
                $("#list1").jqGrid({
                    url: "GetNotesReportDetails",
                    postData: { startDate: $('#startDate').val(), endDate: $('#endDate').val(), ins_Type: $("#InsuranceType").val(), ass_Clincian: $("#ddlAssignedClician").val() },
                    datatype: "json",
                    mtype: "POST",
                    colNames: ["ID", "#", "First Name", "Last Name", "Date Of Birth", "Date of Visit", "Insurance Type", "Insurance ID","Clinician" ,"Procedure Code", "Fee Schedule"],
                    colModel: [
                            { name: "ID", index: "ID", hidden: true, key: true },
                            { name: "SNo", index: "SNo", width: 10, align: "left" },
                            { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 40, align: "left", sortable: true, formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:', showAction: "Link('", addParam: "');" } },
                            { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 40, align: "left", sortable: true, formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'javascript:', showAction: "Link('", addParam: "');" } },
                            { name: "DateofBirth", index: "DateofBirth", width: 40, align: "left", formatter: 'date', sorttype: "date", sortable: true },
                            { name: "DateofVisit", index: "DateofVisit", width: 40, align: "left", formatter: 'date', sorttype: "date", sortable: true },
                            { name: "PageType", index: "PageType", width: 40, align: "left", sortable: true },
                            { name: "InsuranceID", index: "InsuranceID", width: 50, align: "left", sortable: true },
                            { name: "Clinician", index: "Clinician", width: 50, align: "left", sortable: true },
                            { name: "ProcedureCode", index: "ProcedureCode", width: 50, align: "left", sortable: true },
                            { name: "CodeFee", index: "CodeFee", width: 50, align: "left", sortable: true }],

                    // Grid total width and height
                    multiselect: true,
                    rowNum: 20,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 15, 20],
                    width: 900,
                    height: "100%",
                    // Paging
                    pager: $("#pager1"),
                    viewrecords: true,


                    // Default sorting
                    //sortname: "FirstName",
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    sortable: true,
                    loadonce: true,
                    hidegrid: false,
                    // Grid caption
                    caption: "Reports List"
                }).navGrid("#pager1", { refresh: false, excel: true, add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, // settings for edit
                                                                                              {}, // settings for add
                                                                                              {}, // settings for delete
                                                                                              { sopt: ["cn"] } // Search options. Some options can be set on column level
                    ).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager1', {
                        caption: "Export to Excel",
                        buttonicon: "ui-icon-bookmark",
                        onClickButton: genGraph,
                        position: "last"
                    });
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have problem in your data. You used `key: true` for the column `ID`. It means that jqGrid will assign the value of `id` attribute of every row (`id` of `<tr>` element) with the value from `ID` column. If you would have **the same** values in `ID` column instead of providing **unique** values you would have exact the same behavior like you described in your question. If jqGrid will need to select or unselect an row then it will search the row by id. It will find **the first row with the id** if one have more as one row with the id. So it will select/unselect the first row in the grid in many cases.

Comment: Yes you are right. it is giving  id="2" for each row. but what could be the solution?

Comment: Awesome you are. yes There was problem in Id

Comment: @Sweetie: You should either fix your input data and provide **unique** id values for each row or you can just **remove** `key: true` property from `ID` column. jqGrid will assign 1,2,3... values as rowids if it will don't find any ids in your input data.

Comment: Can you pl suggest me how can I get every selected row from the grid. I need to export those selected rows.

Comment: @Sweetie: One need be able to get/edit or etc the data and sent it back to the server you have to have an unique value in every row which would enough to identify the row. Do you have an native ids in the table of database? Do you have as other combination of data like `SNo`, `InsuranceID` or `LastName`+`FirstName` which construct **unique** identifier of the item of the data?

Comment: yes. I have the coloum "ID" which is hidden . It is the PkId of the table.

Comment: @Sweetie: Sorry, but PkId from the table must be unique. Probably you fill the data with SELECT having INNER JOIN from more as one database table, but you use `ID` only from one table, so you get non-unique ids for the SELECT query. You should analyse the SELECT query and to find one value or one combined value (like `CAST(id1 AS varchar(10)) + `_` + `CAST(id2 AS varchar(10))`). To have better advice one need to see the query which generate the data from the grid.